# Hive: Is there any way to customize hiveInputFormat?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Here's the scenario: 3 folders are located in hdfs. The files are as follows:

```
/root/20140901/part-0
/root/20140901/part-1
/root/20140901/part-2
/root/20140902/part-0
/root/20140902/part-1
/root/20140902/part-2
/root/20140903/part-0
/root/20140903/part-1
/root/20140903/part-2
```

After creating a hive table whose command is as below, I invoke hql=[`select * from hive_combine_test where rdm > 50000;`], this will cost 9 mappers, just the same number as the files in hdfs.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL table hive_combine_test
(id string, 
rdm string)
PARTITIONED BY (dateid string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'
stored as textfile;

ALTER TABLE hive_combine_test
ADD PARTITION (dateid='20140901')
location '/root/20140901';

ALTER TABLE hive_combine_test
ADD PARTITION (dateid='20140902')
location '/root/20140902';

ALTER TABLE hive_combine_test
ADD PARTITION (dateid='20140903')
location '/root/20140903';
```

**But what I want is to make all the part-i together in one split, in such way, there should be only three mappers**.

I've tried to inherit from `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat` in order to test whether the custom `JudHiveInputFormat` can work.

```
public class JudHiveInputFormat<K extends WritableComparable, V extends Writable>
                    extends HiveInputFormat<WritableComparable, Writable> {

}
```

But when I mount it in hive, it returns exception:

```
hive> add jar /my_path/jud_udf.jar;
hive> set hive.input.format=com.judking.hive.inputformat.JudHiveInputFormat;
hive> select * from hive_combine_test where rdm > 50000;

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.judking.hive.inputformat.JudCombineHiveInputFormat
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:880)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:870)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Could anyone give me some clue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what are you doing in the JudHiveInputFormat?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know to add a custom INPUT/OUTPUT format in Hive you need to mention that format in your create table statement. Some thing like this:

```
CREATE TABLE (...)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT '<your input format class name >' OUTPUTFORMAT '<your output format class name>';
```

Since you need only InputFormat, so your create table statement will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE (...)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'JudHiveInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

Why you need to mention this OUTPUT format class, since you have overwritten the INPUT format Hive expects the OUTPUT class as well, so here we need to say Hive to use its DEFAULT OUTPUT format class.

May be you can give it a try.

Hope it helps...!!!